Initialization app service azure devops pipeline
I work with Azure DevOps, and I need to set up a pipeline release where a build artifact is deployed to an Azure App Service. The problem is that after the deployment, the app service must be started in the development environment to perform initialization (such as database setup and so on).
Is there a way to automatically perform the initialization after the deployment and then move on to the next stage, which is "Change Environment to Production"?
Regarding the "Change Environment to Production" stage, I know how to do this in the release with the Azure App Service Settings stage.
My issue is that I don’t know how to perform the initialization before changing the environment from Development to Production.
I would handle this easily if it were a single app, but since it involves many apps, I want everything to be automated.


Can you clarify what you mean by saying "perform initialization (such as database setup and so on)"? 2. "I would handle this easily if it were a single app" - How did you handle this when there is one app? 3. What's your app type?


I developed the application using Blazor. In the development environment, it needs to perform migrations
When it comes to a single application, I can simply use the pipeline to deploy it, run app, initialization make, and then switch the environment to 'production'.

I don't understand what the difference is when there are multiple apps.

Because I want everything to be automatic, as I have hundreds of app services


Because I want everything to be automatic, as I have hundreds of app services

If you are using the classic release pipeline, I'm afraid you need to create a release pipeline for each app.
It's suggested that you could use yaml pipelines. Define the info of each app in the parameter and use the each function to read each app and deploy it. For example,

parameters:
- name: MyApps
  type: object
  default:
  - appName: zyweb1
    appType: webAppLinux
  - appName: zyweb2
    appType: webAppLinux

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: 'Build Apps'
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    # your build steps

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - ${{ each app in parameters.MyApps }}:
    - deployment: Deploy_${{app.appName}}
      displayName: 'Deploy_${{ app.appName }}'
      environment: $(environmentName)
      pool:
        vmImage: $(vmImageName)
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - task: AzureWebApp@1
              displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: ${{ app.appName }}'
              inputs:
                azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
                appType: '${{app.appType}}'
                appName: '${{ app.appName }}'
                package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
                runtimeStack: 'NODE|18-lts'
           # Your initialization and switching the environment steps 

Sample results:


Can I perform slot warming up without the swap function?

Check whether this ticket is helpful for you.
